# How to click on elements which are located in cell of the table Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, pageobjects

I wrote method that gets  text value from cell ​​by row number and column name.

```
public String getValueFromCell(int rowNumber, String columnName){
        List<Map<String, WebElement>> rowsWithColumnsByHeadings = getRowsWithColumnsByHeadings();
        return rowsWithColumnsByHeadings.get(rowNumber - 1).get(columnName).getText();
    }
```

But there are icons in cells(as you can see in the screenshot, there can be one,two, or four icons)
[image: Icons with Xpath]

And now i want to click on  all of  them. Or click on specific icon

And i must admit that this table is located on many pages with different count of icons in cell, and i want to use this method for all of them.

How can i modify this method? Or what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below solution:

If you want to click on specific icon element then you can use rowNumber index to click on it, Just check otherwise use moveToElement using Action class before while clicking onto the element:

```
public String getValueFromCell(int rowNumber, String columnName){
        List<Map<String, WebElement>> rowsWithColumnsByHeadings = getRowsWithColumnsByHeadings();
        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("mat-icon.mat-icon.notranslate.material-icon.mat-icon-n0-color"))
        elements.get(rowNumber).click()
        return rowsWithColumnsByHeadings.get(rowNumber - 1).get(columnName).getText();
    }
```

or if you want to click all of them one by one :

```
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("mat-icon.mat-icon.notranslate.material-icon.mat-icon-n0-color"));
    elements.forEach(e -> {
        e.click();

    });
```

Comment: Great , glad to hear that.